# What are the health benefits of consuming oligonol?

Tags: diet, immune-system, fruits

Oligonol are [polyphenols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphenol) found in [lychee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychee) fruit.

[image]

<sup>Image credits: [Loving Themes](http://lovingthemes.com/health-benefits-lychee-fruit/)</sup>

I've heard that it has antioxidant properties which can fight the virus infections and it's used as a natural remedy for a number of health problems.

What are the health benefits of consuming it (oligonol)?

Comment: Is oligonol supposed to be good (or bad) for health? Without any context, I don't get the question.

Comment: I believe 'health benefits' indicates it's about what's good for health.

Comment: But why should it be good? Have you heard something, or read something, for example?

Comment: @Shlublu I've added the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible Risks**

[This study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17081671) suggests that Oligonol is safe for consumption and does not pose any proven threats or harmful consequences to health (1 & 2).

**Possible Benefits:**

Other studies suggest that its benefits may include reducing:
visceral fat (5),
the risk of mental degenerative diseases such as dementia and Alzheimer's (6), stress-induced inflammation (7),
and excessive sweating (8).

There's also possible correlation with strengthening the immune system (9).

**Disclaimers** (Thanks JohnP!)

- These studies don't suggest that Oligonol is a panacea, but rather
  indicate *possible* benefits.
- In many of them, there are the same scientists cited as authors.
- (Sources 1 & 2) *Conflict of Interest Statement:* [The authors] are employees of Amino Up Chemical Co., Ltd. and BAM and AR are consultants to Amino
  Up Chemical Co., Ltd. - (A biotechnology company that produces nutraceuticals and functional food ingredients.)

> Oligonol is a particularly promising source of
>   polyphenols since it provides higher concentration of phenolic
>   monomers and oligomers, and thus the **bioavailability of these
>   polyphenols are higher, with *potential* for enhanced beneficial health
>   effects.**

...

> The use of Oligonol to produce an antioxidant benefit in human beings
>   **needs to be studied in future clinical trials**.

(See more: Links 3 and 4)

---

**Sources:**

1. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17081671
2. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278691508002949
3. http://oligonol-net.com/e/publication/conference.html
4. http://oligonol-net.com/e/applications/circulate.html
5. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1756464609000565
6. [Oligomerised lychee fruit-derived polyphenol attenuates cognitive
   impairment in senescence-accelerated mice and endoplasmic reticulum
   stress in neuronal cells.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23537529)
7. [Protective role of oligonol from oxidative stress-induced
   inflammation in C6 glial cell.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25861417)
8. [Oligonol Supplementation Modulates Plasma Volume and Osmolality and
   Sweating After Heat Load in Humans.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25602687)
9. [Oligonol supplementation affects leukocyte and immune cell counts
   after heat loading in humans.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24962480)

Comment: To be noted: Over half of those studies are either lead or co-authored by the same person, who is in the employ of AminoUp (Who is actually listed as the author info for the first study you linked). One of AminoUp's main products is oligonol supplements. There are a couple interesting other studies in your links though.

Comment: Good point. I noticed the recurring authors and conflict of interest note at the bottom, keeping it in mind, but should probably mention that in the disclaimer too.

Comment: That might be a good idea :) Also, I'm not familiar with all the magazines that publish studies, but I don't recognize most of the ones that these are published in. I'd have to see if @susan or anongoodnurse has a better handle on their reputation.

Comment: Fingers crossed, but many of them are based in Japanese or alternative medicine associations.

Comment: @DaveL Thanks for your answer. I think another more recent study from [2014](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24326174) also confirms its safety.